# Is there a tool or a way to upload the arduino sketch without using the arduino IDE directly?

Tags: arduino

I am making a head mouse and my product requires a user interface to set the mouse sensitivity . Is there a tool or a way to re-upload the arduino sketch with the updated value of the mouse sensitivity.?

This is for a human computer interaction device (a head mouse) for which I have to ship the product with a UI to achieve customer friendliness. The UI should take the mouse sensitivity as input to suit the customer and update it for the arduino without using the arduino IDE directly. I've tried using megunolink but I can't really use it for financial restrictions from the client. And I am using the arduino Pro Micro which is not listed in the compatibility list of Megunolink. Even if I can use Megunolink, I have no idea how to make it compatible for arduino Pro Micro.

Comment: your UI should update configuration, not the firmware

Answer (score 0):

You can program AVR microcontrollers with [AVRDUDE](https://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/). I believe the Arduino IDE uses AVRDUDE internally.

As you will most likely not deliver a programmer with your device I assume you have some communication interface between the UI and the microcontroller.
Consider storing sensitivity values in EEPROM rather than replacing the entire firmware.

Comment: Can I use AVRDUDE to input something in the serial monitor too?

Comment: @NahianRifaatAlindo I don't understand what this would be good for

Comment: I need the user to train the voice recognition module before using the device. Normally, I would just open the serial monitor and type my command to train it. But when I ship the device, I can't make the user open the serial monitor of the IDE. So, I have to make him indirectly access the serial monitor and train the module.

Comment: @NahianRifaatAlindo provide a UI with your device that does the serial communication.